# Create a word document from a list that contains an image and a table with Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have the `.rmd` file in which after downloading and saving into my working directory this image below with the name `bl_convergence_acorr001.png` I create a list which contains that image and a table. Then Im trying to create a word document through `Rmarkdown` but instead of the image and the table I create a word document with this list printed.
[image]

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "makis"
date: "March 14, 2019"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r t3, echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE}
library(officer)
library(magrittr)
library(flextable)


current_dir <- getwd()

my_doc <- read_docx() 

current_dir <- getwd()

my_doc <- read_docx() 

#####
#with baseline
#Baseline Autocorrelation Plots
bl_acorr_files=list.files(path = current_dir, pattern = c("^bl_convergence_acorr",".png"))

for( i in 1:(length(bl_acorr_files))){
  my_doc <- my_doc %>%
    slip_in_text(paste0("Figure 1 Baseline Autocorrelation Plots"), style = "strong", pos = "after") %>%
    body_add_img(src = paste0("bl_convergence_acorr00",i,".png") ,height = 5.75, width = 10 ,style = "centered")
}

summary_stats <- iris
ft <- flextable(data = summary_stats) %>%
  theme_booktabs() %>%
  autofit()
my_doc <- my_doc %>%
  slip_in_text(paste0("Table 2: Summary stats"), style = "strong", pos = "after") %>%
  body_add_flextable(ft)
my_doc
```
````

Comment: Maybe you can try using the `kable()` function on the list element from the `knitr` package?

Comment: and what about the image?

Comment: You are mixing officer code into a R Markdown document. This will not work. officer does not pour its content (`my_doc`) in a markdown file.